# Rotate the query of the table horizontally in PHP getting the thead of a different table of the tbody

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

Doesn't anyone know how to rotate the result table from a join of tables ?

Better explain

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfMhV.jpg)

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojQnM.jpg)

and finally this is my code:

```
<div id="encuesta">
<?php
$y = 0;
$Query1 = $Conexion->query("SELECT ID_Encuesta,Encuesta_Nombre FROM encuestas");
while($row1 = $Query1->fetch_assoc())
{
    $y++;
    $x = 0;
    ?>
    <h4><?php echo $y; ?> - <?php echo $row1['Encuesta_Nombre']; ?></h4>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="table<?php echo $row1["ID_Encuesta"]; ?>">
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $Query2 = $Conexion->query("SELECT ID_Pregunta,Pregunta_Nombre,Pregunta_Pregunta,Pregunta_Tipo FROM preguntas WHERE pregunta_encuesta = '$row1[ID_Encuesta]'");
            while($row2 = $Query2->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td class="bg-primary" style="color:white;">'.$row2['Pregunta_Nombre'].' </td>';
                $Query3 = $Conexion->query("
                        SELECT 
                        (
                            CASE 
                                WHEN A.Pregunta_Tipo = '1' THEN C.Etiqueta_Numero
                                WHEN A.Pregunta_Tipo = '2' THEN B.Respuesta_Respuesta 
                                WHEN A.Pregunta_Tipo = '3' THEN B.Respuesta_Respuesta 
                                WHEN A.Pregunta_Tipo = '4' THEN C.Etiqueta_Numero
                                ELSE 1
                            END) AS Respuesta
                        FROM preguntas AS A
                        JOIN respuestas AS B
                        ON A.ID_Pregunta = B.Respuesta_Pregunta
                        LEFT JOIN etiquetas AS C
                        ON B.Respuesta_Respuesta = C.ID_Etiqueta
                        WHERE B.Respuesta_Pregunta = '$row2[ID_Pregunta]'
                ");
                while($row3 = $Query3->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo '<td>'.$row3['Respuesta'].'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
    <?php
}
?>
```

well, to explain my code, the first `$Query1`  is a consult to the `encuestas` table to get the `thead` and the relation with the `$Query2`,

The `$Query3` its to get the value what I need to show on the `tbody`.

Here is my DB [SQL Fidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ba6d2)

Comment: you could get all these values in 1 query using joins, then build up your table from there. don't put queries in the middle of your view files, they should ideally be separated into models and controllers should combine the query and your views

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

You can change your query

or you can change your php code.

```
            while($row3 = $Query3->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo '<td>'.$row3['Respuesta'].'</td>';
            }
```

To change your query I need to see how the database looks like etc.

For the php code

You can push the code in an array list.
and then push the arraylist into the tables.

I suggest you change the query.

Comment: Hello @Mo, I already updated my question with a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ba6d2), thank you for answer, I have open mind for all suggeration I know my code is not the better, Im still learning

Comment: I thought about your code and I think the best solution is to do it this way https://jsfiddle.net/r0nyk4ap/   It's easier. If you do it your way you will have a long row because the database data must be added to each other. you could also do in your header v1 v2 v3 v4 v1 v2 v3 v4.... but it will not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one array with your results and call this method, it will to transpose an array and then print your table again, check this sample https://3v4l.org/v9VsV

```
function transposeArray($array)
{
    $i         = 0;
    $transpose = [];
    while ($columns = array_column($array, $i++))
    {
        $transpose[] = $columns;
    }
    return $transpose;
}
```